# Linq Query Check with List (of string)

Tags: vb.net, linq

How to check list of string values from Linq query?

`_extnsn` is a list of string with values (.bmp, .jpg, .tga, ...).

I want to get these type of files with Linq query so I tried like that:

```
 dim _FileCOllections = From _file In _dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    Where _extnsn.All(Function(xf) _file.Extension.ToLower = xf.ToLower)
    Order By _file.FullName Ascending
    Select _file
```

Return value is nothing.

Comment: if you join to your list on extension equals xf that should do the trick.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `_extnsn.All`? To me it sounds like you meant `_extnsn.Any`.

Comment: thanks antdc and Micha Wiedenmann ...ANY is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have a DirectoryInfo object and a sequence of file extensions as string. You want a query that keeps only those files in your directory that have an extension that matches one of the file extensions.

```
DirectoryInfo _dirInfo = ...
IEnumerable<string> fileExtensions = ...

IEnumerable<FileInfo> filesWithDesiredExtensions = _dirInfo.EnumerateFiles()
    .Where(fileInfo => fileExtensions.Contains(fileInfo.Extension));
```

**Oops. I see you want it in VB!** Sorry, maybe this might be of any use for C# readers

By the way, did you see I used [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of GetFiles? This has the advantage that if you only want FirstOrDefault, or maybe Take(2), you don't have to fetch all FileInfos. Just an optimization

Comment: ooh datz great ... i changed my code now "_dirInfo.EnumerateFiles" so we will get faster than getfiles method am i correct !!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Are you sure you want to use _extnsn.All? To me it sounds like you meant _extnsn.Any. – Micha Wiedenmann

i just changed `_exntsn.All` to `_exntsn.Any`

```
       Dim _exntsn As New List(Of String) From {".jpg", ".png", ".tga", ".tif"}
            _FileCOllections = From _file In _dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                                               Where _exntsn.Any(Function(k) k.ToLower = _file.Extension.ToLower)
                                                               Order By _file.FullName Ascending
                                                               Select _file
```

It's working fine for me,  i can get these particular extension image collections ... thanks .. Micha Wiedenmann and all.